# Using CSS to make button animate

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two buttons animate from small to large on hover using `CSS`. I have the following which does make the button change but without no animation. (**button.png** and **buttonHover.png** are the same pixel width and height - but the images are of a small button with a transparent surround and a large button).

It may well be that this is the wrong way to do it - this is the first time I have trued this.

```
a.button {
background: url(button.png) no-repeat 0 0;
width: 150px;
height: 62px;
display: block;
line-height: 62px;
text-align: center;
font-size:9px;
color: white;
}

a.button:hover{
    background: url(buttonPressed.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
-webkit-animation: myButton 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 animation: myButton 1s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myButton {
    background: url(buttonHover.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myButton {
    background: url(buttonPressed.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: You can't animated background images.

Comment: Feel free to add the image to the question and we can see if it can easily be remade in CSS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for keyframes; use `transition`.

As Zach [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299956/using-css-to-make-button-animate#comment41269196_26299956), background images can't be animated between. You should recreate the backgrounds in CSS.

[From the MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

> The CSS transition property is a shorthand property for `transition-property`, `transition-duration`, `transition-timing-function`, and `transition-delay`. It allows to define the transition between two states of an element. Different states may be defined using pseudo-classes like `:hover` or `:active` or dynamically set using JavaScript.

### Example

In this example, the "all" indicates that every difference between the normal state and `:hover` that can be animated should transition over 0.5 seconds. [Here is a complete list of animated properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Use the appropriate browser prefixes before the non-prefixed transition as needed. Depending on your needs, browser prefixes could be unnecessary. [Have a look over here on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) for an overview of browser support.

```css
  a.button {
    background: #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 62px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 62px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  a.button:hover {
    background: #F00;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<a class="button">Button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. The fact that I can't animate the image itself explains the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im leaving you a working example on how to implement it. Hope it helps.

```
button {
    width : 100px;
    height: 20px; 
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
        width : 150px;
        height: 30px;
}


<button>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1oa8tw0h/1)

Comment: I see this. But this is a transition in size. What I want to do is fade actual image. I guess that is not possible.